# HP Data Protector - very long backup duration

Tags: windows, backup

I perform incremental backup of my files on more servers everyday .

The last two days time to backup is longer than usual:

Last monday: Start time 21:00:05 End Time: 23:35:34

Yesterday: Start time 21:00:05 End Time:  08:40:31 (today)

There are no errors in logs

In log of this execution I do not see any pieces of information beetwen 21:26:06 and 08:40:31

```
[Normal] From: BMA@a01mbackup.my_company.com "HP:Ultrium 3-SCSI_1_a01mbackup"  Time: 21.09.2015 21:26:01
COMPLETED Media Agent "HP:Ultrium 3-SCSI_1_a01mbackup"

[Normal] From: BSM@a01mbackup.my_company.com "File"  Time: 22.09.2015 08:40:31

Backup Statistics:

    Session Queuing Time (hours)         0,00        
    -------------------------------------------      
    Completed Disk Agents ........          8          
    Failed Disk Agents ...........          0          
    Aborted Disk Agents ..........          0          
    -------------------------------------------      
    Disk Agents Total  ...........          8          
    ===========================================      
    Completed Media Agents .......          1          
    Failed Media Agents ..........          0          
    Aborted Media Agents .........          0          
    -------------------------------------------      
    Media Agents Total  ..........          1          
    ===========================================      
    Mbytes Total .................    3894 MB        
    Used Media Total .............          1          
    Disk Agent Errors Total ......          0
```

How can I analyse this problem? Are there any detailed pieces of information?

Answer (score 0):

In MFC GUI go to  file->preferences->debugging-> 
1.debug range 1-200
2. debug file name  debug.txt
3. Use these settings permanently
-> relaunch GUI now...

run your session. now check current session debugs in Programdata->omniback->tmp.